# Concurrency in a D program

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, d

I am trying to write a simple D program with two threads (main and one spawned in main) with a daughter thread  receiving message from the parent thread. Here is my piece:

```
import std.stdio;
import core.thread;
import std.concurrency;
import std.c.stdio;

extern (C) int kbhit();

void readSignal(){  
    for(;;){
        bool stop = receiveOnly!bool();
        if(!stop)
            writeln("reading signal...");
        else
            writeln("stop reading signal...");
        Thread.getThis.sleep(1.seconds);
    }   
}

int main()
{
    auto reader = spawn(&readSignal);  
    bool stop = false;

    while(true){        
        if(kbhit()){                                    
            stop = true;
        }

        option 1: reader.send(stop);        
        option 2: send(reader, stop);       
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

Basically I wait for a keyboard hit and the *intend* to pause the spawned thread.
Neither of options (option 1 by [Andrei Alexandrescu](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1609144&seqNum=5) and option 2 as in [dlang docs](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_concurrency.html)) work for me. What do i do wrong?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't very descriptive. *what* doesn't work, does the value passed not change, is the signal never sent,...

Comment: Yeah. More details are needed to help you very well, particularly since your code fails to compile as-is. And there really isn't any semantic difference between options 1 and 2. There can be depending on what the imports are or what the member functions for `reader` are, but in almost all cases, they're the same. If `reader` has a `send` member function, then option 1 would call that instead of a free function, whereas option 2 would always call a free function, but the compiler will turn option 1 into option 2 if `reader` doesn't have a member function called `send`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that your main thread is spinning very hard, sending thousands and thousands of messages to the reader.  The reader, however, is only reading one per second.  The 'true' message is backed up behind a massive number of 'false' messages.

For a situation like this, you may be better off using a `shared` variable, rather than using messages.  Both threads will be able to safely read and write from it.

Comment: You understood it right. But once keyboard is hit, it _must_ be sending thousands and thousands of **True** messages and therefore the reader must adjust its behaviour, but it does not, this puzzles me. I ll give a try to a shared variable.

Comment: Once the keyboard is hit it will send thousands of trues _but_ there are thousands of falses in the queue which will be dequeued by your thread before the true can be handled ... one every second. Why don't you move the send to the if {}?

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned you are flooding the client thread.
Try adding a sleep like this

```
Thread.sleep(dur!"msecs"(1500));
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by duselbaer and Anders S, in your example, the number of `send`s is huge, but the number of `receive`s is limited by the `sleep`. So, when the thread should actually get a `true`, it is already preceded by an overwhelming number of `false`s in the queue.

Generally, if the child thread is able to receive faster than the parent thread sends, it's fine. Here is a working example produced from your code. The `sleep` calls may be substituted by doing some work, but the relation must generally hold.

```
import std.stdio;
import core.thread;
import std.concurrency;
import core.stdc.stdio;

extern (C) int kbhit();

void readSignal() {
    for(int i = 0; ; i++) {
        bool stop = receiveOnly!bool();
        if(!stop)
            writeln("reading signal... ", i);
        else
        {
            writeln("stop reading signal...");
            break;
        }
        Thread.getThis.sleep(1.msecs); // this should be no more than below
    }
}

int main() {
    auto reader = spawn(&readSignal);
    bool stop = false;

    while(!stop) {
        if(kbhit()) {
            stop = true;
        }

        send(reader, stop); // option 1
        // reader.send(stop); // option 2 does the same thing as above via UFCS
        Thread.getThis.sleep(1.msecs); // this should be no less than above
    }
    return 0;
}
```